# angularjs - copy the directive element in the template

Tags: angularjs-directive

I'm creating a directive that should be applied on any HTML element and "use" the same element in it's children.

Imagine going from this:

```
<some_standard_html_tag my-directive></some_standard_html_tag>
```

to

```
<div>
  <some_standard_html_tag></some_standard_html_tag>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

In other words, I basically want to surround the element the directive is in a `div` and add some other elements to that same div.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for [ngTransclude](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angTransclude).

You can use transclude to mark the place where you want elements that are defined inside the directive to be injected into the directive template.

Comment: ngTransclude does what you say, copies the contents inside the directive. However I need the element it self, not only it's content

Comment: After all it was my mistake, and indeed the ngTransclude with also `transclude:'element'` option worked as I wanted.